# Basic graphQL Mongoose set up

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, mongoose-schema, graphql-js

I have followed http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-server/guide.html/ and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHabPhgRUuU) and want to try connecting it to db at www.mlab.com. The project is connecting to mlab and graphiql but when i run a query in graphiql im getting null/undefined values for my query.

This is schema.js

```
const typeDefinitions = `
type Biz {
 name: String
 address: String
}

type Query {
 biz(name: String, address: String): Biz
}

schema {
 query: Query
}
`;

export default [typeDefinitions];
```

This is connectors.js:

```
// businesses in mongo DB
    const MONGOLAB_URI = 'mongodb://user:password@ds064278.mlab.com:64278/klik-mongodb';
    const mongo = Mongoose.connect(MONGOLAB_URI, function (err, res) {
     if (err) {
       console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + MONGOLAB_URI + '. ' + err);
     } else {
       console.log ( 'Succeeded connected to: ' + MONGOLAB_URI );
     }
    });

    const BizSchema = Mongoose.Schema({
     _id: Object,
     address: String,
     city: String,
     country: String,
     heading: String,
     headingid: Number,
     img_url: String,
     name: String,
     objectId: String,
     phonenumber1: String,
     website: String,
     latitude: Number,
     longitude: Number,
    });

    const Biz = Mongoose.model('bizs', BizSchema);

    export { Biz };
```

this is resolvers.js:

```
import { Biz } from './connectors';

    const resolvers = {
     Query: {
       biz(_, { name, address }) {
         return Biz.find({ where: name, address });
       },
     },
    };

    export default resolvers;
```

This is an example of my mlab object:

```
{
               "_id": {
                   "$oid": "573e8c9b1379f0f2fad98290"
               },
               "accountid": 1404,
               "address": "737, Grand Rue,",
               "city": "Port-au-Prince",
               "country": "Haiti",
               "createdAt": "10/26/2015 7:27:42 PM",
               "heading": "Computer, Printers and Supplies",
               "headingid": 323,
               "img_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/klik-io/image/upload/v1454850817/pages-jaunes-haiti-icon_sosoco.png",
               "name": "A & M Entreprises",
               "objectId": "0lw9lVl23j",
               "phonenumber1": "+509 3770 0303",
               "website": "http://868.ht"
            }
```

This is the graphiql output:
[image]

Comment: take a look in this boilerplate https://github.com/sibelius/graphql-dataloader-boilerplate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your biz resolver uses `find()`, which will return a list.  What you want is `findOne()`.

PS: You can usually debug this kind of problem by adding a print statement in the appropriate resolve functions (or running the node debugger).

Comment: Thanks. findOne worked to get one result. I was hoping to get a list which is why i used find(). Thanks for taking the time. I still dont know what I dont know. Wiill try print and debugger. Thanks again.